# Why is my BeautifulSoup text search with special characters failing to retrieve my element?

Tags: regex, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2 and Beautiful Soup 4.  I have this snippet of HTML ...

```
<p class="tagline ">submitted&#32; on 2/20/2019</p>
```

I would like to retrieve this element and so I have created the below code ...

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, features="lxml")
...
pattern = re.compile(r'^submitted\&\#32\;')
submitted_elt = bs.find(text=pattern)
```

Unfortunately, the submitted_elt is always None.  What else do I need to do to tweak my regular expression to search for this element?  I don't want to have the word "submitted" all by itself, because that will return too many elements.

Comment: gave it a try, but nothing doin'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `&#32;` is an HTML character code for a space (verify HTML character codes [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html)) and when BeautifulSoup parses this html, it translates it into an actual space in your soup. You can verify it by printing it out. Putting a space at end of submitted as a pattern (`'^submitted '` instead of `'^submitted&#32;'`) causes it to work.

Comment: Thanks for this info, but in my question I did mention, 'I don't want to have the word "submitted" all by itself, because that will return too many elements.'

Comment: It's technically not all by itself since there is a space after it and matches the exact HTML that you were looking for. But if that is not the goal, I would attempt to accomplish it with just the re module and the HTML string itself.

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't realize "&#32;" was the code for a space.  Now I understand and your solution works great.  Thanks!  I was having a hard time with that one.

Comment: It's all good. It was kind of hard to explain, and I couldn't even type that HTML char code into StackOverflow because it translates it to a space. I know that it's still pretty general as ```'submitted '``` so maybe you could check for two spaces in a row after it to narrow down your results.